# How many XUSER's

Tags: x11, who

I'm working on a script an I need to show how many people are logged into XServer. It was suggested that I look at the last part of the who command (N:N):

```
 user1  tty7         2013-10-10 12:14 (:0)
```

I'm trying to find information on this an having trouble finding it. Any info would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the display and screen information. When you're within an X session, you should find something like `:0` in `$DISPLAY`.

This number is broken down into two parts: the first number is the display number:  this generally is a group of devices that contains one or more screens, with one or more input devices. The screen number gives the specific screen being within that group.

The `$DISPLAY` syntax is similar to the host and port specifications that are common in networking. Fully fleshed out, it looks something like `hostname:display.screen`. For example, if you were referring to display 2, screen 1 on example.com, you would use the syntax `example.com:2.1`.

`:0` is shorthand for "the first display".